# Western Digital External HD won't mount

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, mount

I have an external HD that I suddenly stopped mounting. It is 5+ years old and is used regularly, but has basically never moved, so while it is possible it is dead, hoping it is something else. First noticed the issue on Mac, but also cannot get it to connect to Win10 PC.

On Windows I can see it listed under disk drives in device manager. Windows does not seem to think drivers need updating.

Under disk management in computer management, I can also see it and it is registering as 'healthy', but is not assigned a volume letter, and all the options are disabled, so 'Change Drive Letter and Paths' is unavailable.

If it were completely dead, I would think that the disk would not even appear.

Everything has been turned on and off a few times, and I have tried a different cable.

Comment: Does it work on any other PC?

Answer (score 1):

On windows you could always try uninstalling the device in windows device manager and then unplug it, and plug it back in to see if re-installing the device driver will fix it.

The nice thing is that its a western digital HDD and western digital so happens to have software on their website to help you diagnose problems with their drives yourself. Download the Data Lifeguard software from their website, its the software for diagnosing problems. They also have other useful software for their drives as well.

[Western Digital Downloads](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en)

Comment: yup - am running that as well - quick scan had not done anything and full can is estimating 6 hours+, so was hoping somebody might have a suggestion. Also had tried the uninstall/reinstall, forgot to mention that, but no luck there. Will report back in 6 hours :)

Comment: also the WD universal firmware updater for windows cannot detect the drive, but the data lifeguard software can... strange...

Comment: @getglad If after WD's tool doesn't help with your problem, you most likely have a failed HDD. One thing you didn't mention from the Disk Management tool is if whether or not if it gives you the option to format the drive. While not something you want to do, if nothing else works, try reformatting the HDD.

Comment: Only option it gives me for the drive is 'delete volume' - all other options are disabled.

Comment: You could always try deleting the volume which what that does, is deletes partitions, even if there is 1 partition. Mainly used for removing extra partitions without formatting the entire drive. Maybe if you remove the partition it might let you format it. Again, this step is best left for last after you try everything as you will lose everything that is currently on the HDD